# How to add a reftex-default-bibliography to latex as a local variable?

Tags: emacs, auctex, bibliography

I have a main reftex-default-bibliography but I want to use a sepecific bib file in my tex file. I am using Emacs-AucTeX-RefTeX.
At the end of my Tex file I wrote:

```
%%% Local Variables:
%%% reftex-default-bibliography: "~/texmf/tex/latex/demo2LatexEmacs/mini.bib"
%%% End:
```

When I try to use the Ref command `\cite` I can only search my main bib file and not the local mini.bib file. Is there anything wrong with the way I wrote the code for the Local Variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The start of the docstring for `reftex-default-bibliography` says:

> List of BibTeX database files which should be used if none are specified.

In other words, it looks like it's expecting a list, so you'll need to enclose your file in parentheses to make it a list of one element:

```
%%% Local Variables:
%%% reftex-default-bibliography: ("~/texmf/tex/latex/demo2LatexEmacs/mini.bib")
%%% End:
```

Comment: It worked but I had to restart Emacs to include Local Variables.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @Dan is correct. I would just like to indicate some essential points.
The issue was solved by using the local variables, including the following code at **the end of the file**:

```
%%% Local Variables:
%%% reftex-default-bibliography: ("/path/to/Reference")
%%% End:
```

The `reftex-default-bibliography` variable indicates to reftex where to find the bibliography file. However, there is not required to give the full path. In case that your file is in the same enclosure folder as the main file, just add:

```
%%% Local Variables:
%%% reftex-default-bibliography: ("./Reference")
%%% End:
```

If the file is one folder up(hierarchically) put:

```
%%% Local Variables:
%%% reftex-default-bibliography: ("../Reference")
%%% End:
```

Finally, you have to execute the command `revert-buffer` to changes take effect .